# Create Step Time Intervals

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop, sequence

I apologize if this incredibly simple as I am relatively new to R, but I have been stuck on this problem for some time and can't seem to find my answer through online searches.

I am trying to create a data frame with one column of minute datetime intervals based on times from a separate data frame ("drops").

```
> head(drops)  
  uid             tid               dtdep              dtpull    nutm     eutm
1 256 A69-1601-27561 2014-04-28 10:14:00 2014-04-28 11:21:00 1966514 329557.4
2 257 A69-1303-54408 2014-04-28 10:22:00 2014-04-28 11:26:00 1966884 329507.1
3 258 A69-1601-27331 2014-04-28 10:28:00 2014-04-28 11:37:00 1967184 329458.8
4 259 A69-1303-31936 2014-04-28 10:38:00 2014-04-28 11:50:00 1968022 329896.8
5 260 A69-1303-54408 2014-04-28 11:32:00 2014-04-28 12:40:00 1966883 329556.9
6 261 A69-1601-27331 2014-04-28 11:45:00 2014-04-28 12:46:00 1967084 329459.0
```

I created an empty data frame to store my output

```
> steptimes<-data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=300,ncol=1))
```

And ran the following for loop, but it is only generating time steps for the fifth row of my drops$dtdep

```
>for(j in 1:5){
>  steptimes[j]<-seq(from=drops$dtdep[j],length=60,by="min")
>}
```

My output looks as follows

```
> steptimes
 [1] "2014-04-28 11:32:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:33:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:34:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:35:00 EDT"
 [5] "2014-04-28 11:36:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:37:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:38:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:39:00 EDT"
 [9] "2014-04-28 11:40:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:41:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:42:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:43:00 EDT"
[13] "2014-04-28 11:44:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:45:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:46:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:47:00 EDT"
[17] "2014-04-28 11:48:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:49:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:50:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:51:00 EDT"
[21] "2014-04-28 11:52:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:53:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:54:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:55:00 EDT"
[25] "2014-04-28 11:56:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:57:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:58:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 11:59:00 EDT"
[29] "2014-04-28 12:00:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:01:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:02:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:03:00 EDT"
[33] "2014-04-28 12:04:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:05:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:06:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:07:00 EDT"
[37] "2014-04-28 12:08:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:09:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:10:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:11:00 EDT"
[41] "2014-04-28 12:12:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:13:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:14:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:15:00 EDT"
[45] "2014-04-28 12:16:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:17:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:18:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:19:00 EDT"
[49] "2014-04-28 12:20:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:21:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:22:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:23:00 EDT"
[53] "2014-04-28 12:24:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:25:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:26:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:27:00 EDT"
[57] "2014-04-28 12:28:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:29:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:30:00 EDT" "2014-04-28 12:31:00 EDT"
```

Which is fine, but I need the step times generated for the other drops$dtdep

Any help would be much appreciated and apologies if this incredibly simplistic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be nicer without the loop:

```
dtdep <- c(as.POSIXct("2014-04-28 10:14:00"), 
          as.POSIXct("2014-04-28 10:22:00"))
drops <- data.frame(dtdep)

steptimes <- lapply(drops$dtdep, function(x){
      seq(from = x, length = 60, by = "min")
})
# As a vector
steptimes <- do.call(c, steptimes)
# As a data frame with one column if this is really necessary
steptimes <- data.frame(steptimes)
```

If you only need times based on the first *n* dtdep elements select those as in `steptimes <- lapply(drops$dtdep[1:5], ...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I am getting the following error message "Error in seq.default(from = x, length = 60, by = "min") : 
  'from' must be of length 1"   I believe this is because "x" is a vector of datetimes and the seq function can only handle single values?  Regardless, thank you for your reply and I will continue working with it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that error. `x` is not a vector but a single element of `drops$dtdep`, that's what `lapply` is for. I edited my answer to include a working example.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you! I think I may have been putting in the wrong object for the lapply function.